# How to create dynamic field in Yii2?

Tags: input, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have one table where I am saving field name.
Now I want to use those fields in another model. So, How can I give name to that field?

e.g. 
 I have table named as Config with `fields(id,key)`.
Data can be

```
1, Blog url
2, Site url
```

Now, I have 1 form where admin will add those value to database.

In Yii2 we create input field like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
```

But I want to create two textboxes with name `blog url` and `site url`.
So, How can I create it? What I have to write in place of `name`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question. Use (inline) code blocks. Check [help].

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Are you trying to use tabular data[1]? If so, are you trying to put a different `label`[2] for each field?

[1]http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html
[2]http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#label()-detail

Answer (score 0):

run this code on your command prompt

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform "*"
```

after completion of above code.

add the following code in your form.
_form.php

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Addresses</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
         <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
            'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
            'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
            'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
            'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
            'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
            'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
            'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
            'model' => $modelsAddress[0],
            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
            'formFields' => [
                'name',
            ],
        ]); ?>

        <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
        <?php foreach ($modelsAddress as $i => $modelAddress): ?>
            <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Address</h3>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php
                        // necessary for update action.
                        if (! $modelAddress->isNewRecord) {
                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelAddress, "[{$i}]id");
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, "[{$i}]name")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on StackOverflow. Please add essential part to answer.